# Get Label Template value of Vorto field in Archetype - Umbraco 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7, archetypes

I have Archetype in umbraco 7.4.3
When i set vorto text box in the archetype i cannot get the correct alias for the label template and i get "object Object" insted.

I know that the label template code inside the "{{}}" is angular-JS but i'm not familiar with this language..

My back office:

[image]

The result:

[image]

If i'm trying to use Object.keys(title) i get 2 keys but i can't find way to get their values... i need the text in the default value or in english

My back office:

[image]

The result:

[image]

the "English (United States)" language prefix in my code is: en-US.

Please someone help me to find how to define the label template !!!

Thanks in advance for all helpers!

Comment: Unfortunately you  might be out of luck trying to do it this way - I would suggest perhaps swapping it - instead of wrapping individual properties in Vorto within Archetype, consider wrapping Archetype in Vorto. You may also find this will avoid other pitfalls that people are finding.

Answer (score 1):

Archetype allows you write your own Label Template functions for more complex types, see the following link: https://github.com/kgiszewski/ArchetypeManual/blob/master/02%20-%20Configuration.md#label-template